# Best Way To Secure Requests (To & From Salesforce Servers)

Tags: web-services, authentication, iis, salesforce, security

This question is not necessarily restricted to Salesforce.

I have a web service on our company server that generates documents based on order information. I have created pages in Salesforce to dynamically create links with necessary order information in the query string.

Example:`https://www.mysite.com/documents?orderid=123&documentid=1`

My web service then makes a request for detailed information for the order from the Salesforce API (First & Last Name, Mailing Address, etc...) and returns the populated document.

I'm considering 2 ways of securing this:

1. Whitelisting the [Salesforce IP Range](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?language=en_US&id=000003652) in my web service and my company's IP in Salesforce.
2. Populating all necessary information in the initial query string. Example: `https://www.mysite.com/documents?documentid=1&firstname=John&lastname=Smith&address=123%20Main`

Which way is "best"? Should I do both? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In what way are you trying to secure it? Just restrict where the request can come from?

Comment: 1st one definitely won't hurt. If you're afraid of other SF clients hacking you - why not demand the incoming request to pass valid session id in the URL ({!$Api.Session_ID}), then use it somehow to obtain user's info/organisation name/make sample select statement via SOAP or REST?